# How to close a leaf in Fossil

Tags: fossil, branching-and-merging

The [documentation on branching in Fossil SCM](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/tip/www/branching.wiki) says a leaf is considered closed if it has a closed tag.  However, when I enter

```
> fossil tag add closed xxxxx
> fossil leaves --closed
>
```

it doesn't show anything as closed.  The same thing happens if I add the tag with `--propagate`. When I check [closed leaves of Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/leaves?closed) itself, the leaves listed have no `closed` tags displayed.  What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `fossil tag add --raw closed check-in`

Another way to do it is start the user interface, go to check-in details and edit its properties (mark as closed)

Comment: The `fossil ui` command is the recommended way to do this. The ui has a lot of features that are hiding behind inconspicuous links.