# associate a commit with a ticket retrospectively

Tags: fossil

When committing, I used by mistake the ActifactID of ticket change instead of the ticket hash label:

```
fossil commit -m "Workaround X [58480ac08c]"
```

In `fossil ui`, it is still a clickable link and leads to the ticket. However, the check-in does not appear under "Check-ins Associated With Ticket".

Is there a way to associate a check-in with a ticket retrospectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the command line, you can use ['fossil amend'](https://www.fossil-scm.org/home/help?cmd=amend).

Answer (score 1):

Found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3787977

In `fossil ui`, open check-in's properties and click on *edit*. The comment text can be changed there (to include the correct ticket hash label).